# Any difference between "I know C did it" and "C did it"?

Tags: word-usage, understanding, logic

I was working on a [logical problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273108/logical-puzzle-3-persons-each-2-statements-1-lie-1-true). In this problem I have a problem with the statement made by B.

B said `I wasn't` `I know C did it`

I thought that the second statement of B means `C did it`.

In the accepted answer you can see that C has (f,t) which means his first statement is false and the second is true.

**If second statement of B is false then how can C be guilty?**

I think there is no difference between saying `I know C did it` and `C did it`.

If there is a difference between the statements then please tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of "C did it" is "C **didn't** do it."

By contrast, the opposite of B's seconds statement, "I know C did it" is "**I don't know** whether/if/that C did it."

It is possible that C did it but B did not know about it; therefore, C can be guilty while B's second statement is false.